# "Hidden" Select List Options Oddly Available Via Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I created some code for easily viewing a collection of the pages in a particular project in an iframe below a select list that is navagable via the Arrow Keys (← / →). It soon became obvious that the list was going to get unmanagably long rather quickly, so I created another select list that would act as a filter so you could view one project at time. When you selected a project from the filter list, it would add a class to all of the other select list option values (*brilliantly* entitled "none") that would shorten the select list considerably.

If you check out the code below (from the rendered source view), you can see the "none" class assigned to the last four items which effectively hid them from the select list, so I thought it was a done deal. However, when you use the Arrow Keys to navigate thru the list, ALL of the options still work. Compounding my problem was my inability to come up with the right search term(s) to help narrow down whatever the real issue is.

Because the code uses query string values to identify the active project, I couldn't get it to work on JSBin or CodePen. Since you really have to see it in action to make sense of my explanation, I put it here: http://nunyabiz.zxq.net/projects/index.html?show=project1

```
<select id="links" target="main">
    <option value="" class="none">---Select Page With Arrow Keys-----</option>
<optgroup label="Project 1" class="projects project1">
    <option value="/projects/project1pg1.php" class="projects project1"> project1pg1.php</option>
    <option value="/projects/project1pg2.php" class="projects project1"> project1pg2.php</option>
    <option value="/projects/project1pg3.php" class="projects project1"> project1pg3.php</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Project 2" class="projects project2 none">
    <option value="/projects/project2pg1.php" class="projects project2 none"> project2pg1.php</option>
    <option value="/projects/project2pg2.php" class="projects project2 none"> project2pg2.php</option>
    <option value="/projects/project2pg3.php" class="projects project2 none"> project2pg3.php</option>
</optgroup>
```

I also included a shortcut to a Bookmarklet that lets you view generated source code very easily, in case it proves to be helpful to anyone. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to try and help me. Much appreciated...

Comment: Is my explanation clear enough or does nobody else have any idea either?

Comment: I have the same problem... Have you found a solution?